# Spring framework vs Object Oriented Programming

Tags: java, spring, oop, architecture, frameworks

By default Spring framework creates all the beans as **singletons**. 
Isn't this contradicting with basic Object Oriented Programing concept of creating multiple object instances based on a template (class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you really think about it, spring does make some practices of OOP really hard/impossible, say:

```
return new Cached(new ImageLoader("cat.png")).load();
```

or

```
return new Parrarel(new ImageLoader("cat.png"), new ImageLoader("dog.png")).load();
```

It's really hard (don't know if even possible) in spring (and most DI frameworks in general).

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't this contradicting with basic Object Oriented Programing concept of creating multiple object instances based on a template (class).

No it isn't.   Spring is using the "templates" under the hood when creating singletons.

OO principles say that multiple objects *may* be created.  They don't say that there *must* be multiple instances of a class if this is not warranted.  And indeed, there is even a classic OO design pattern that supports this<sup>1</sup>.

And besides, when it is warranted the Spring framework can create multiple instances.

---

<sup>1 - The Singleton design pattern has its issues (configuration versus code, testability, etc), but it is not going against OO programming principles in any way.  Interestingly, a DI framework like Spring actually helps to address the short-comings of the Singleton pattern.</sup>